# Preseleced Check icon dont show in console log

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Goal:
Show preselected data of selected checkbox in console.log

Problem:
The preselected data don't show in the consolelog.
If I make a manual check, the data will show.

What part am I missing?

Info:
I'm new in angular

Thank you!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfq9cu

Comment: I'm not sure why you made your code this way and if you really need all the FormControl related stuff for something else later, but your code sample could be much easier to achieve the exact same thing. You should check ngModel as the answer below suggested it, but also check about the `change` event on input fields with angular. You don't actually need the Form related classes for this.

Comment: Do you have a sample or something similar that I can learn from your perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be use the **ngModel** property to bind the values.

Instead this

```
[checked]="musicPreferences[i].checked"
```

Use this

```
[ngModel]="musicPreferences[i].checked"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fork of your stackblitz with some of the changes I was talking about in my comment:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3uhecx

I removed all the Form-related stuff from the component, and worked instead with `ngModel` and `change` event. I also simplified the `*ngFor` loop, you didn't need to keep track of the index for this.

Again, I don't know what you intend to do with your form. FormBuilders are great and are the correct way to go if you have a complex form that need some sort of validation. If you only have that checkbox list, then I don't think you need something as complex as FormBuilders, you could work with ngModel and regular events like in my sample.